# Document library item - send email by workflow on insert

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

I have a separate form that interacts with users. The form prompts them for data, and this is put into a separate SharePoint document library.

The Columns for the document library are

- Name
- Modified
- Modified by
- Status
- Supervisor Email

The user is asked for the supervisor email as well as other information, this is then placed in the document library.

How do I have it so that the value for the list item "Supervisor Email" is used to send an email to the supervisor when this separate form is filled out and submitted?

The form is able to create a document in the SharePoint document library, but I am unable to have the workflow send an email to the supervisor the user inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Joe,

You should not take Supervisor Email as input, instead take a People field for Supervisor and the person submitting the document should select the Supervisor from People Picker field...

Then you can use this people field to send emails in workflow... Let me know if you require more step-by-step solution!

Here is a screen-shot how you can access fields of current item inside the workflow action "Send Email":
[image]